# Unexpected text 'await' when opening database with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I'm following the [Persist data with SQLite](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite) tutorial from the Flutter Dev website, and I'm trying to open a database connection using `async`, but I keep getting the error `Unexpected text 'await'`. Even when I copy the code directly from the tutorial I'm still getting the same error.

This is my full file:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

// Open the database and store the reference.
final Future<Database> database = openDatabase(
    join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'doggie_database.db'),
);
```

As far as I can tell I'm using the keyword correctly, so why is the compiler complaining?

I'm using `Dart 2.7.0-dev.2.1` if that makes a difference.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @JoãoSoares Thanks for your answer, it appears to have solved the problem on the surface but now the compiler is getting past that point it's chucking up lots more errors with other modules not loading, so I'm trying to work out the root cause before I mark it as accepted.

Comment: that's perfectly reasonable. If you want to share what the issues are, I can try to help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This seems like an issue with asynchronicity. It's strange that an example from the official documentation is leading you into this mistake. Directly assigning a variable outside of a method that would need to be `async`. Try this:

```
final Future<Database> database = getDatabasesPath().then((String path) {
  return openDatabase(join(path, 'doggie_database.db'));
});
```

For future reference, the reason why the OP's code wasn't working was because he was running it outside of the `main()` Flutter method, which is async in the example provided by the Flutter documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite#example